# How can I use Eclipse to debug tests driven by sbt?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, scala-ide

I have a set of test cases that I want to debug (step by step, reading values, etc.). How can I setup my `sbt` build so that I can hookup an eclipse debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to attach the Eclipse debugger. To the `Build.scala` project settings I add the following options:

```
//required for the javaOptions to be passed in
fork := true

javaOptions in (Test) += "-Xdebug"

javaOptions in (Test) += "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

Then in Eclipse I can create a new `Debug configuration` (arrow next to the bug icon) of type `Remote Java Application`. There I can select `Scala debugger (Socket Attach)` and specify the port `5005`.

Problem I now have is that I cannot set any breakpoints, but that's another question and might be related to the version of Scala IDE that I use.

### Edit

Problems with setting the breakpoint had (most likely) something to do with the exotic constructions in my specs2 specification. I created a small object with a method in order to be able to set a breakpoint

```
object BreakPoint { 
  def set = {}
}
```

Comment: If you can reduce the breakpoint problem to a reproducible test case, we will like to know about it: 
http://scala-ide.org/docs/community.html.

Comment: Good point as soon as I have some time I will try to make an isolated test case

Comment: And make sure to use the latest Scala IDE release (at the time of this writing, v3.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Scala debugger` through the remote connector works.

But if you want to avoid to go back and forth between `sbt` and `Eclipse`, you can load your project in `Scala IDE` using [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse), and then run your specs2 tests from inside `Scala IDE`, in debug mode, using the [JUnit launcher](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/testingframeworks/index.html#specs).

Comment: I use sbteclipse, really nice! The JUnit launcher would not be a good choice here because I am using [Auto Examples](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Auto-Examples) that are longer than one line.